# Recycler View Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

**I am new to android studio and java

I'm trying to bind a button to an activity that contains a recycler view and the adapter that comes with it. The problem is when I click on the button the activity crashes. I know the button is not the problem because I have a different activity that uses a button and goes to the activity.

The problem is in either the activity for the recycler view which is named EdwardActivity or the adapter and I can't seem to figure it out.

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.edu.pfrfitness, PID: 10520
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.edu.pfrfitness/com.edu.pfrfitness.EdwardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.edu.pfrfitness.EdwardActivity.onCreate(EdwardActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10520 SIG: 9
```

Activity for recycler(named Edward Activity):

```
package com.edu.pfrfitness;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class EdwardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String s1[], s2[];
    int images [] = {R.drawable.black, R.drawable.black, R.drawable.black, R.drawable.black, R.drawable.black, R.drawable.black};


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_row);

            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

            s1 = getResources() .getStringArray(R.array.Navigation_List);
            s2 = getResources() .getStringArray(R.array.description);

            MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, s1, s2, images);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

            //call recycler
        }


        public void  Recycler(){

        }






    }
```

Adapter:

```
package com.edu.pfrfitness;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    String data1[], data2[];
    int images[];
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context ct, String s1[], String s2[], int img[]) {
            context = ct;
            data1 = s1;
            data2 = s2;
            images = img;


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.edwardText1.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.edwardText2.setText(data2[position]);
        holder.edwardImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView edwardText1, edwardText2;
        ImageView edwardImageView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            edwardText1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edwardText1);
            edwardText2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edwardText2);
            edwardImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edwardImageView);
        }
    }


}
```

My row so like how each row will look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/edwardImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edwardText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Navigation_List"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edwardImageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edwardText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="description"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edwardText1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edwardText1" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**Error explanation:**
According to the error you are trying to call *setLayoutManager* function on a null object. So, your variable "recyclerView" is obviously null.

**Reason:**
The reason is that in your activity you do this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_row);
```

and you use the file "my_row.xml" to create your Activity layout. But, in this layout there is no view with id **recyclerView**. So, when you do this:

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

then variable recyclerView is set to **null**.

**Solution:**
I guess that by mistake you used file "my_row.xml" as the Activity's layout, since this layout was obviously created fot the adapter's items. You should instead use another layout for the Activity's layout by passing it in your *setContent* in Activity's *onCreate*.